# Two questions on the ring S := {a+bs : a,b ∈ R}

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Let $s$ be a formal symbol.

Define addition and multiplication
operations on the set
$S := {a+bs : a,b ∈ R}$ (with curly brackets)
by the rules

$(a+bs)+(c+ds) := (a+c)+(b+d)s$,

$(a+bs)(c+ds) := (ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)s$.

a) Find $α, β ∈ R$ such that $s^
2 = α+βs$.

b) By considering the product $( √
2+s)( √
2−s)$ inside $S$ or otherwise,
prove that $S$ is not a field. [8]
[You may assume that multiplication in $S$ is associative.]

For a), I took $(0 + 1s)(0 + 1s) = α + βs$, which gave me $α = 2, β = 0$, so $s^2 = 2$... is this correct?

For b), the product is $0$ (which is logical since $(√2−s) = 0$), but what ring axiom does this fail? The only real candidate is the multiplicative inverse law, but I can't yet see how.

Comment: $\sqrt2-s$ which is the same as $\sqrt2+(-1)s$ is not zero in $S$.

Comment: $S$ with the exception of the multiplying factor $\sqrt{2}$, is very close to split-complex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number), which itself is some representation of $\mathbb R^2$. Similarly we have $j^2=1$ while $j$ not being $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Your answer is correct: $s^2=2$.

b) In a field, if the product of two elements is $0$, then (at least) one of them is $0$, which is not the case here.

Comment: I see... I was thinking something along those lines, but wasn't sure... thanks!